# Complex htaccess with multiple RewriteRules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a problem when configuring .htaccess for my site. I'll try to explain my best:

- Suppose my site is: example.com
- My site offers content in english or spanish
- Pages are the same for both languages. Only language strings vary.

The first thing I try is to force www and https:

```
 - if user types http://example.com
 - if user types https://example.com
 - if user types http://www.example.com
he is always redirected to https://www.example.com
```

Now I try to "beautify" my site. I am trying to offer example.com for english visitors and example.com/es for spanish visitors. Languages are applied by a query string "language=english" or "language=spanish". I want to make internal redirects.

I am trying to apply these rules when visiting different pages. I'll try to expose all possible redirects:

- example.com, example.com/ and example.com/index.php --> index.php?language=english
- example.com/webpage.php --> webpage.php?language=english
- example.com/es, example.com/es/, and example.com/es/index.php --> index.php?language=spanish
- example.com/es/webpage.php --> webpage.php?language=english

Of course, there is no "es/" folder. All is made internally.
There is also a categories page i.e. example.com/category.php?id=1
I prefer to use "beauty" links, so example.com/category/1/loremipsum.php must redirect internally to category.php?id=1

And my goal is to make categories work with languages, i.e.

- example.com/category/1/loremipsum.php --> example.com/category.php?id=1&language=english
- example.com/es/category/15/requiesqat.php --> example.com/category.php?id=15&language=spanish

I think maybe it is impossible to do everything. I am willing to mix php, cookies etc. I appreciate any suggestion.

This is my .htaccess:

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName example.com
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# 1. Force HTTPS and WWW
# Case 1: NO HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
# Case 2: NO WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

# Module for languages
# This 2 blocks are for spanish: example.com/es
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!language) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es(/|/index.php)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php?language=spanish [S=3,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!language) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/es(/)(?(1)(.*)?)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^es/(.*)?$ $1?language=spanish [S=2,NC,QSA]

# This 2 blocks are for english: example.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!language) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/|/index.php)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?!es|es/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?language=english [S=1,NC,QSA]

# This is the problematic paragraph. If I left previous ones, website works properly,
# except for webpages other than "index.php". So I add this to deal with all the other
# pages and redirect to english site. It redirects internally but it does not change
# language. It seems that query string ?language=english is not good.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!language) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?!es|es/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?language=english [NC,QSA]

# Categories
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.php$ category.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: No mention of what input generates unexpected output, or the resulting rewritelog.

Comment: I edited my question. I have added an explanation on top of problematic code. It is the 2nd block of code for english language.